# Regex for Decimal Number with limits

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to write a regex for allowing 3 digit numbers followed by optional decimal, integer part cant be greater than 180 or smaller than -180. example of valid enteries are 156.56, 56.778, 9, 6.7.etc etc.
So far I came up with this `^(\+|-)?:180|1[0-7][0-9]|[0-9][0-9]|[0-9]?([\.][0-9]{1,3})?$` but these seems to match 195.678 too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of doing that, why not just have two checks? One makes sure that you match the pattern, and the other makes sure that the value is between -180 and 180.

```
/-?\d{3}(\.\d{1,3})?/.test(val) && (val <= 180 && val >= -180)
```

The resulting solution is far easier to understand and maintain, and not to mention, saner :).

The reason your regex doesn't work is that the `^` and `$` don't match across the entire pattern. You have the different conditions in your regex that are separated by `|`. The `^` is associated with the first option, and the `$` is associated with the last option. This is easy to see in the following example:

Assume you had the regex `/^[0-9][0-9]|[0-9]$/`. If you tested this against `12345` what would you get? You might be inclined to say that it would return `false`, but it actually returns `true`. This is because there is a valid match! The `12` in `12345` will match against `^[0-9][0-9]`. So what you're saying is that you want to match against any two numbers at the beginning of the string or against a number at the end of the string. Basically *any* string that has at least two numbers at the beginning **or** one number at the end, will match. So `12abc` will match, as will `abc1`.

However, if you changed the regex to `/^([0-9][0-9]|[0-9])$/`, only one and two-digit numbers will match. This is because the beginning and end-of-string anchors are outside the matching group, meaning the entire group has to match. This is something that you have to consider when you have conditions in your regex.

**EDIT**

Also, Tim points out:

> ... there is a colon where it shouldn't be: ^(+|-)?:180 matches :180, +:180 or -:180 and nothing else

Comment: Agreed. Fancy regexes can potentially check values for limits, but it'll be far nastier than a logical and. Not to mention how much cheaper it will be computationally.

Comment: :) Agreed!! and I will accept your ansewer. Still would like to know what I am doing wrong .

Comment: Also, there is a colon where it shouldn't be: `^(\+|-)?:180` matches `:180`, `+:180` or `-:180` and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

Since you introduce the possibility of leading 0's, something like this
should validate the entire range:

`^(?:\+|-)?(?:180(?:\.0{0,3})?|(?:0{1,3}|0{0,2}[1-9]|0?[1-9][0-9]|1[0-7][0-9])(?:\.[0-9]{1,3})?)$`

**test** in Perl

```
use strict;
use warnings;


my $regex = qr/
^
 (?:\+|-)?
 (?:
      180 (?:\.0{0,3})?
   |
     (?:
          0{1,3}
        |
          0{0,2}[1-9]
        |
          0?[1-9][0-9]
        |
          1[0-7][0-9]
     )
     (?:\.[0-9]{1,3})?
 )
$
/x;


for ('000' .. '180')
{
   my $num;

   $num = -1 * $_;
   if ( $num =~ /$regex/) { print "$num\t" }
             else { print "($num failed)\t" }

   $num = 1 * $_;
   if ( $num =~ /$regex/) { print "$num\t" }
             else { print "($num failed)\t" }

   $num = '+' . $_ . ".$_";
   if ( $num =~ /$regex/) { print "$num\t" }
             else { print "($num failed)\t" }

   $num = '-' . $_ . ".$_";
   if ( $num =~ /$regex/) { print "$num\t" }
             else { print "($num failed)\t" }

   print "\n";
}
```

Output:

```
0       0       +000.000        -000.000
-1      1       +001.001        -001.001
-2      2       +002.002        -002.002
-3      3       +003.003        -003.003
-4      4       +004.004        -004.004
-5      5       +005.005        -005.005
-6      6       +006.006        -006.006
-7      7       +007.007        -007.007
-8      8       +008.008        -008.008
-9      9       +009.009        -009.009
-10     10      +010.010        -010.010
-11     11      +011.011        -011.011
-12     12      +012.012        -012.012
-13     13      +013.013        -013.013
-14     14      +014.014        -014.014
-15     15      +015.015        -015.015
-16     16      +016.016        -016.016
-17     17      +017.017        -017.017
-18     18      +018.018        -018.018
-19     19      +019.019        -019.019
-20     20      +020.020        -020.020
-21     21      +021.021        -021.021
-22     22      +022.022        -022.022

<snipped>

-172    172     +172.172        -172.172
-173    173     +173.173        -173.173
-174    174     +174.174        -174.174
-175    175     +175.175        -175.175
-176    176     +176.176        -176.176
-177    177     +177.177        -177.177
-178    178     +178.178        -178.178
-179    179     +179.179        -179.179
-180    180     (+180.180 failed)       (-180.180 failed)
```