# filter out a percentage from a string using a regular expression in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following string value: £-155 (-2.2%)

Out of that I want to be able to extract anything that is a number and may/may not contain a '-' minus sign. so the above would be: -2.2

I also need to know whether the value has a percentage in the form as above or not...a conditional statement will be used in the final code.

thoughts?

Comment: wouldnt -155 be a number by your definition too?

Answer (score 0):

Why use regex for something so simple? Why not just grab the last character in the string and check if it's a digit or a %.

Likewise, if you want to remove it, just drop the last character from the string using the .substr() method:

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_substr.asp

Comment: Erm, because the test string has stuff other than the number?

Comment: Wow...I totally missed that part. Do a regex based on this: string.match(/\((.*)\)/) to get everything in brackets....then use substr.

Answer (score 0):

You basically want a regex that matches a number, which has been [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4690986/regex-needed-to-match-number-to-2-decimal-places) [many](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9840462/php-and-preg-match-regex-to-pull-number-with-decimal-out-of-string) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1831419/whats-the-shortest-regex-that-can-match-non-zero-floating-point-numbers-with-an) [before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7690476/regex-for-decimal-number-with-limits).

Then once you have that, just add an optional percent symbol (`%?`) and check for its presence in the matched string.

Answer (score 0):

```
// An optional sign and either an integer followed by an optional fraction
// or a decimal fraction.
var numberRe = '[+-]?(?:[0-9]+(?:[.][0-9]*)?|[.][0-9]+)';

// Matches a number (in group 1)
// and an optional percentage in parentheses (in group 2).
var quantity = new RegExp(
    '(' + numberRe + ')(?:\\s*[(]\\s*(' + numberRe + ')\\s*%\\s*[)])?');
```

If you match with `quantity` you should get the number in group 1 and any percentage in group 2.

> ```
> JSON.stringify(quantity.exec('£-155 (-2.2%)'))
> ["-155 (-2.2%)", "-155", "-2.2"]
> ```

To get them as numbers, use `parseFloat` or unary `+` as in

> ```
> var match = quantity.exec('£-155 (-2.2%)');
> var n = +match[1], pct = match[2] != null ? +match[2] / 100 : NaN;
> alert('n = ' + n + ', whole = ' + (pct ? n / pct : "unknown"));
> ```